# Start gazebo headless mode based on launch config argument

Tags: simulation, gazebo, ros2, roslaunch

I was trying to start a simulation in ingition gazebo based on a condition.

**condition**

launch argument : **headless_mode** (bool) -> default : False

```bash
if headless_mode : 
     start simulation in headless mode
else :
     start simulation normally
```

The launch file that I have written is given below, The problem I am having is that the condition is not working by externally setting the **headless_mode** to **true**

```py
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess, DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration


def generate_launch_description():
    sim_dir = get_package_share_directory('simulation')
    world_launch_file = os.path.join(sim_dir, 'sdf', 'world.sdf')

    # Choose ignition headless rendering mode
    headless_mode = LaunchConfiguration('headless_mode')
    declare_headless_mode_argument = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'headless_mode',
        default_value='False',
        description='Whether to render ignition headless or not'
    )

    # World launch process
    world_launch = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=["ign", "gazebo", "-r"]
        + (["-s"] if (headless_mode == "True") else [])
        + [world_launch_file],
        output="screen",
        condition=IfCondition(use_ign_sim),
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        declare_headless_mode_argument,
        world_launch,

    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Track down [`headless` in Nav2](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bringup/launch/tb3_simulation_launch.py#L50) for an example of how it works.

It's worth reading the [Launch architecture readme file](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/galactic/launch/doc/source/architecture.rst) to get some context about how to work with substitutions and actions in this environment.